# Embed App Store in my app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

I see games in the App Store that allow you to download other games. Rather than app switching to the App Store to download the other game, it brings up an embedded App Store within the app itself.

Zoo Country is an example of an app that does this.

The only way I know of to bring someone to the app store to download another app is to do something like this, but this switches apps:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms://itunes.com/apps/appname"]];
```

How is Zoo Country embedding the App Store?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use the `SKStoreProductViewController` class. Docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Yeesh. 3 UV's for a link to the docs. I wish I could do that.